# Arduino Map equivalent function in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, range, arduino

Is there a function similar to the [Map](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Map) function in Arduino for Java?

I need to map a range of values to another range of values, so I was wondering if there was something similar to it in Java, I've been searching but I only get the Java's Map function.

Comment: I was too quick to post, in the bottom the Arduino documentation page shows the code to do it:

Comment: deleted my answer because it was exactly what you said

Comment: Dang, I looked up the code. Who expects the implementation inside the *long* documentation? :-)

Comment: Please note the criticism of the map() function: [link](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,46546.0.html) when porting it to Java.

Answer (score 30):

The code of `map()` from Arduino's library is this:

```
long map(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max)
{
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

This will work in Java just the same - no real magic. But standard Java has nothing predefined like this.

Comment: Watch out for the rare case when `in_max`, `in_min` and `out_min` are zero, since there division by zero will throw an `ArithmeticException`

Answer (score -1):

Uh, Java doesn't have a 'Map' function, it has a [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) type in the Collections (java.util), with multiple implementations. But this is just a storage mechanism, basically resulting in key=>value pairs. Based on my reading of the Arduino docs you linked, you'd need to implement your own method to map the value appropriately.

Comment: Look at the question, it is about mapping a relative value according to a definite min / max value.